# Disable freeshipping for 2 states in USA

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, free-shipping

I am Trying to disable Free-shipping For 2 states in USA other States have free-shipping eligibility and I have set up table rates for these 2 states its getting worked.

But I don't want to show the free shipping for this 2 states I have tried to create a cart price rule but its not getting worked please find the following images can any one help me to disable free-shipping for ony hawaii and Puerto rico

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"is not"` option instead of `"is"` and apply free shipping for all other so it will be worked.

Check below image for more information.
[image]

Check following for Action tab

[image]

Comment: in action what i need to set? can you give me a screen shot for that

Comment: check my updated ans

Comment: @ i have updated like this but still it showing free shipping please check my checkout screen shot

Comment: have you removed that two states from table rates ?

Comment: @ Aasim Goriya i have added these tho states on table rate look at the screen shot of my table rates the table rate working fine it will ony show if i choose hawaii o rportio

Comment: So what you want now ?

Comment: @ Aasim Goriya actually for my site we have free shipping in USA except these two states(Hawaii,Portio) . For this two staes i need to add shipping rates as $45 currently when i choose other states it showing only freeshipping but when i choose hawaii or portio it showing both free shipping and table rate here i need to show only the table rate

Comment: I think you have missing some thing in your setting, so please re check your shipping settings also please re check cart price rule

Comment: @ look at my shipping settings did you find any mistakes there?

Comment: @ Aasim Goriya is there an way to workout this i have tried this last two days and there is no change how to check the cart price rule working or not in any other way

Comment: Is there any solution?